# Should my JSON data contain a nested field versus duplicate information?

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I will be importing data in a JSON file into Google BigQuery and would like to know if it is best practice to nest fields and add a field with schema mode "repeat" in order to avoid duplication or leave the duplicated information to have less nesting. Another reason to leave the duplicated information is, because, as far as I can tell, BigQuery works best with denormalized data. However, I am not sure if this denormalization should be done after or before the data import.

For example, assume my data is:

**Nested version**

```
{
   "store": "Pete's Market",
   "city": "NYC",
   "product": [
      {
          "id": "2468",
          "item": "apple",
          "price": "$1"
      },
      {
          "id": "1357",
          "item": "cereal",
          "price": "$3",
          "brand": "Cheerios"
      }
   ]
}

# The actual JSON data file will have this in one row:
# {"store":"Pete's Market","city":"NYC","product":[{"id":"2468","item":"apple","price":"$1"},{"id":"1357",item":"cereal","price":"$3","brand":"Cheerios"}]}
```

**Duplicated information version**

```
{
   "store": "Pete's Market",
   "city": "NYC",
   "product":
      {
          "id": "2468",
          "item": "apple",
          "price": "$1"
      }
}
{
   "store": "Pete's Market",
   "city": "NYC",
   "product":
      {
          "id": "1357",
          "item": "cereal",
          "price": "$3",
          "brand": "Cheerios"
      }
}

# The actual JSON data file will have this in two rows:
# {"store":"Pete's Market","city":"NYC","product":{"id": "2468","item":"apple","price":"$1"}}
# {"store":"Pete's Market","city":"NYC","product":{"id":"1357",item":"cereal","price":"$3","brand":"Cheerios"}}
```

**Extra notes**

There could be be thousands of `products`, the field with mode repeat in the nested version. Some `products` may have fields that others do not. The fields in each `product` could have 2-3 more nested levels.

**Question reiterated**

Is it best practice to nest fields and add a field with schema mode "repeat" in order to avoid duplication or leave the duplicated information?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is write-once or append-only, then there is only slight usability difference (explained below), either one works fine, with normalized one being slightly cheaper to store and scan.

Minor usability difference:

```sql
-- With nested schema
SELECT *  -- here all product's sub fields are entering parent namespace and no way to rename them in batch
FROM table, UNNEST(product) prd
```

But if you want to update only certain Product later, nested Product makes it pretty difficult to do, because there is no way to update single item in REPEATED field, you have to load the whole array, scan and change, and repack to update a column. You will be writing something like:

```sql
UPDATE table
SET product = (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(...) FROM UNNEST(Product) WHERE ...)
WHERE ... -- filter to specific products
```

In this case, denormalized form will be easier to deal with.